# What should be considered when purchasing a portable projector?

Tags: pico-projector

I keep moving to several places and I always want a second display for my laptop, so I am thinking of buying a [pico projector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_projector).

What should I look for in a pico projector?

p.s.: I use my second screen for playing movies and TV-series while I work on the main screen.

Comment: Pico projectors make great toys, but not all of them produce enough lumen to use in anything but a darkened room. So test it in a room without closed curtains.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations ?

Comment: No. I went with a regular projector after all pico projectors failed to live up to my expectations. But that was 5 years ago and I assume that there has been some progress since.